# distinguish use cases in NSAutosaveElsewhereOperation

Tags: cocoa, core-data, autosave, nspersistentdocument, nsfilewrapper

I try to add AutoSave support to the [Core Data File Wrapper example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PersistentDocumentFileWrappers/Introduction/Intro.html)

Now if i have a new/untitled document `writeSafelyToURL` is called with the  NSAutosaveElsewhereOperation type.

The bad thing is, I get this type in both typical use cases
 - new file: which store a complete new document by creating the file wrapper and the persistent store file
 - save diff: where the file wrapper already exists and only an update is required.

Does somebody else already handled this topic or did somebody already migrated this?

The original sample use the `originalStoreURL` to distinguish those two use cases, which solution worked best for you?

Thanks